# How to lock a process in RAM (make it unswapable)

Tags: memory, process, swap

Is there a way to instruct the kernel (Linux kernel) to never swap a certain process that has already been started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly from the command line, you would have to do something with the mlock(2) or mlockall(2) functions. There is some discussion of this on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578137/can-i-tell-linux-not-to-swap-out-a-particular-processes-memory)